# Get stars format from object number field in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to get stars format from object number field(Ex:account object number field length is 5 then we need to display 5 stars). It is possible give me examples

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that you've already tried and what part of it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. use static resource to add all the images like for 1 start image to 5 start image. And now create a formula field on Account object return type text. There check if number field is 5 then display image from static resources using IMAGE formula.

You code will like this

```
IF ( FIeldName__c ==5, IMAGE("STATIC_RESOURCE_IMAGE", "NAME"), '')
```

Comment: Hi Ratan, Thank you for your help But we need to display number wise stars in visualforce page (Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/grv_bajpai/msLLQ/8/ ).once we are get stars in visualforce page click edit button change stars and click save button then update stars into number field object

Comment: @Mahitha so use this code in vf page.. and when you click on stars just grab the integer number and save it to variable. this is the VF page code for after save you can display the image like the solution I provided you above

Comment: Hi Ratan, just now we got result thank you for your help